# Strange conversion in Python logic expressions

Tags: python, python-2.7, boolean-logic, evaluation

I noticed a strange behavior of Python 2.7 logic expressions:

```
>>> 0 and False
0
>>> False and 0
False
>>> 1 and False
False
>>> False and 1
False
```

and with True in place of False

```
>>> 0 and True
0
>>> True and 0
0
>>> 1 and True
True
>>> True and 1
1
```

Are there any rules when Python convert logical statement to integer? Why does it show sometimes 0 insted of False and 1 insted of True?

What is more, why does it return this?

```
>>>"test" or "test"
'test'
```

Comment: `>>> bool('x')` is `True`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing is being converted; the Python boolean logic operators instead *short circuit*.

See the [boolean operators documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations):

> The expression `x and y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is false, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.
>
> The expression `x or y` first evaluates `x`; if `x` is true, its value is returned; otherwise, `y` is evaluated and the resulting value is returned.

Moreover, numbers that are equal to `0` are considered falsey, as are empty strings and containers. Quoting from the same document:

> In the context of Boolean operations, and also when expressions are used by control flow statements, the following values are interpreted as false: `False`, `None`, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets and frozensets).

Combining these two behaviours means that for `0 and False`, the `0` is *considered* false and returned before evaluating the `False` expression. For the expression `True and 0`, `True` is evaluated and found to be a true value, so `0` is returned. As far as `if` and `while` and other boolean operators are concerned, that result, `0` is considered false as well.

You can use this to provide a default value for example:

```
foo = bar or 'default'
```

To really convert a non-boolean value into a boolean, use the [`bool()` type](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bool); it uses the same rules as boolean expressions to determine the boolean value of the input:

```
>>> bool(0)
False
>>> bool(0.0)
False
>>> bool([])
False
>>> bool(True and 0)
False
>>> bool(1)
True
```

To complete the picture, values that are not considered false in a boolean context are instead considered true, including any custom classes. You can change that by implementing a [`.__nonzero__()` special method](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__) on your class. If no such method is defined, [`.__len__()`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__) is consulted as well. With either of these methods you can signal that your type is either numeric and should be considered `True` if non-zero, or it is a container and should be considered `True` if not empty (has a length over 0).

Comment: But why "True and 0" isn't False, but 0?

Comment: @bzxcv17: Again, short-circuiting; the first expression (`True`) is a true value, and thus the second value is returned. `0` is considered false, so as far as `if` and `while` and other boolean contexts are concerned, that is a false value.

Answer (score 4):

Python always return one of the operand objects

`and` returns the first "false" object or the final "true" object.

`or` returns the first "true" object or the final "false" object.

Note that all `0`, `0.0`, `False`, `""` are regarded as "false".

```
>>> "a" and "b" and "c"
'c'
>>> "a" or "b" or "c"
'a'
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because `0` is s falsy value itself.

```
>>> bool(0)
False

>>> bool(1)
True
```

`0 and True` is `0` because `0` is Falsy ,`AND` condition stops executing as soon as first falsy value is found and returns that value. If all values were True then the rightmost value is returned.

`OR` will keep on checking values until first `True` is not found otherwise it returns the last value.(righmtmost)

From the [`docs`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing):

Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an if or while condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below. The following values are considered false:

> - None
> - False
> - zero of any numeric type, for example, `0, 0L, 0.0, 0j`.
> - any empty sequence, for example, `'', (), []`.
> - any empty mapping, for example, `{}`.
> - instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a  `__nonzero__()` or `__len__()` method, when that method returns the integer zero or bool value False.

All other values are considered true — so objects of many types are always true.

Operations and built-in functions that have a Boolean result always return 0 or False for false and 1 or True for true, unless otherwise stated. (Important exception: the Boolean operations or and and always return one of their operands.)

Comment: And `>>> bool(1)` is `True`

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan ah! yes, added that as well.

Comment: Ashwini you should also add this also `>>> bool('x') is True` and `bool('') is False`